# ajax only executing first iteration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
    <?php 
    error_reporting(0);
    //$SITE_URL="http://shreebalajiinfotech.com/Android/Download_videos/";
    $SITE_URL="http://localhost/";
    $DIR="Videos";
    if($_REQUEST['category']=="")
    {
        echo 'Please pass folder name';
    }
    $dir    = $_REQUEST['category'];  
    $result = array();
    $SUB=$DIR ."/" .$dir;
    //var_dump(is_dir($DIR ."/" .$dir));
    //$image="http://shreebalajiinfotech.com/Android/Download_videos/Videos/test1/119064635524.jpg";
    $cdir = scandir($SUB); 
    //$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
    //print_r($cdir);       
    ?>      
        <div id="video_container">
        <?php           
        foreach ($cdir as $value)
         //for ($i=0; $i<count($cdir); $i++) 
         {
       //  if ($cdir[$i] != '.' && $cdir[$i] != '..') 
         //{
        //{             
        if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
        {
            /*echo "<pre>";
            var_dump(each($value));
            echo "</pre>";
            echo $value;
            */              
            //echo $key[$value];                
            //print_r($cdir[$i]);
            $values=explode('.',$value);                
            if($values[1]=="mp4")
            {                   
                //$result[]=$value;
                //echo $cdir[$i];
                //echo "<br/>";
        ?>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = function (){
       // $(document).ready(function(e) {
         //$('#submit<?=$value;?>').click({   
        var video = document.getElementById('my_video_<?=$value;?>');
        var thecanvas = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
        var img = document.getElementById('thumbnail_img');
        var div = document.getElementById('Imagecontainer');
        var sources = document.getElementById('video<?=$value;?>');
        alert(sources.src);
        var videoname=sources.src.substring(sources.src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            setTimeout(video.pause(draw(video, thecanvas, img,videoname)),6000);
         if(video.paused==true)
         {
                setTimeout(video.play(),2000);
         }
         function draw( video, thecanvas, img,videoname )
         {
         alert(video);
        // get the canvas context for drawing
        var context = thecanvas.getContext('2d');
        // draw the video contents into the canvas x, y, width, height
        context.drawImage( video, 0, 0, thecanvas.width, thecanvas.height);
        // get the image data from the canvas object
        var dataURL = thecanvas.toDataURL();
         alert(dataURL);
        // set the source of the img tag
        var img1 = document.createElement('img');   
        img1.setAttribute('src', dataURL);  
        document.getElementById('Imagecontainer').appendChild(img1);
        img1.setAttribute('src', dataURL);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: {image: dataURL,folder:'<?=$_REQUEST['category'];?>',videoname:videoname},
        success: function(response) { 
                alert(response);
               }
                });
       }
        };
        </script>
        <video id="my_video_<?=$value;?>" class="<?=$value;?>" controls autoplay>
        <source id="video<?=$value;?>" src="<?=$SITE_URL.$SUB ."/".$value;?>" type="video/mp4"  />
        </video>
           <canvas id="thecanvas">
        </canvas>
        <div id="Imagecontainer"></div>
        <img id="thumbnail_img" alt="Right click to save"/>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <br/>
        <?php
        }
        }
    ?> </div>
```

The above code iterates only for first element in foreach loop. For the other elements, it takes only the value of first element sometimes, but sometimes it gets squeeze. for each loop only executes on windows load event, How to make this script to execute for another event.

Comment: That's a lot of code to read through, and a lot of it is just html. If you cut out all the stuff that's irrelevant to the logic (comments, most of the html, php that isn't related to your issue) and just include the bare minimum to show the problem, you'll be far more likely to get responses.

Comment: I have edited this code.. please check this.

Comment: Without doing a closer look I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the line `window.onload = function (){` within the `php` loop. The generated html code has multiple script blocks all overwriting `window.onload` so only the last block will _win_.

Comment: i noted your point.but on document.ready if i call then it will do same thing.so what should i do to execute it in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do too much in your foreach loop. It's spitting out tonnes of window.onload functions, which just makes no sense to the poor browser that's trying to understand your intentions. In this case, I think you should just pass the array of video files you have in php into a javascript array. Something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>     
    window.onload = function (){
        var videos = <?php echo json_encode($cdir); ?>

        for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++)
        {
            //Setup each video
        }
    };
</script>
```

This works by encoding the php array in a format known as "javascript object notation", which javascript can handily use to create an array. Once you have the array in javascript rather than php, you can loop through each on the client side, *inside* the window.onload function, which should resolve the issue you're having.

Comment: Hi.. I have tried in with json_encode but it is not working properly.My script must have <video> element to capture an image of this.How it could be accomplish with this??

Comment: Where I have "//Setup each video", that's what I mean. Create any required elements, populate them, etc. How you choose to implement that is entirely up to you - you've not actually explained what you want the page to do, so no one else can help you there.

Comment: Inside the for loop, you can use `videos[i]` to get the exact same data as you had in `$value` inside the for loop of your original script. You should be able to do whatever you need to do with this data, no? Give it a go, and ask a question if you hit a specific problem that you can't find an answer for.