# How can i pass a database array values from PHP to ajax and from ajax to PHP(using ajax post method)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get an array of all the ID's and the database and output the in the html tag, which was successful, now i want to update the values from the database using ajax post method, but the ajax can only locate the 1st value in the database, meaning it's not getting it as an array, but a single value.
**HERE IS THE PHP CODE**

```php
    <div class="chat-contents">
        <div class="chat-content-wrap">
            <div class="chat-wrap-inner">
                <div class="chat-box">
                    <div class="task-wrapper">
                        <div class="task-list-container">
                            <div class="task-list-body">
                                <div id="status">
                                </div>
                                <ul id="task-list">
    <?php
        $sql_p = "SELECT * FROM task";
        $query_p = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_p);
        while ($row_p = mysqli_fetch_array($query_p)) {
            # code...
            $task_id = $row_p['task_id'];
            $project_idss = $row_p['project_id'];
            $task_desc = $row_p['task_desc'];
            $task_status = $row_p['status'];


        ?> 
                                    <li class="task">
                                        <div class="task-container">
                                            <span class="task-action-btn task-check">
                                                <span class="action-circle large complete-btn" title="Mark Complete"
                                                                                id="add-tasks" type="submit" onclick='ajax_taskcomplete();'>
                                                    <i class="material-icons">check</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="text" id="new-task" value="<?php echo $task_id; ?>" />
                                            <span class="task-label" contenteditable="true">
                                                <?php echo $task_desc; ?>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="task-action-btn task-btn-right">
                                                <span class="action-circle large" title="Assign">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="action-circle large delete-btn" title="Delete Task">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
                                <div class="task-list-footer">
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

**HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```js
    <script >
        function ajax_taskcomplete() {
            // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
            var url = "ajax_taskcomplete.php";
            var fn = document.getElementById("new-task").value;
            // var ln = document.getElementById("Description2").value;

            // var st = document.getElementById("statuss").value;
            // var pd = document.getElementById("pros").value;
            // var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
            //+"&Desc="+ln+"&statuss="+st+"pros="+pd
            var vars = "Title=" + fn;
            hr.open("POST", url, true);
            // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
            hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                    var return_data = hr.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
                }
            }
            // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
            hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<img src='assets/img/preloader.gif' alt='Processing...'>";
        }
     </script>
```

JSON STATE:

```
0: {task_id: "6", task_desc: "frontend", project_id: "3", company_id: "Sphere", user_id: "1", …} 1: {task_id: "7", task_desc: "Backend", project_id: "2", company_id: "Sphere", user_id: "1", …} 2: {task_id: "14", task_desc: "peanut lebel", project_id: "1", company_id: "Sphere", user_id: "1", …} 3: {task_id: "21", task_desc: "netflix page", project_id: "1", company_id: "Sphere", user_id: "1", …} length: 4
```

Comment: Looks like your writing over each iteration in your while loop. Define those variables as arrays first. `$task_id = array();` then `$task_id[] = $row_p['task_id'];` Try var_dump on the variable after you define it as $row value to make sure you are gathering all the pertinent info before you send your ajax.

Comment: @dalelandry it is still taking the first value in the row as the general ID for all, below is the correction i made according to your code                                                      <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sphermanager");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM task");

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{
   // array_push($data, $row);
   $data[] = $row; 

   foreach ($data[0] as $datas) {
    # code...
   $var = var_dump($datas);

   }
   //var_dump($data[])

echo json_encode( $var );
}

exit();

?>

Comment: When you var_dump the $row_p, what are you getting? Do you get all the expected values in that array?- insert the answer into your question if you can.

Comment: @dalelandry yes i do, here's the output:                            string(1) "6" string(8) "frontend" string(1) "3" string(6) "Sphere" string(1) "1" string(19) "2020-04-29 01:14:32" string(1) "3" nullstring(1) "6" string(8) "frontend" string(1) "3" string(6) "Sphere" string(1) "1" string(19) "2020-04-29 01:14:32" string(1) "3" nullstring(1) "6" string(8) "frontend" string(1) "3" string(6) "Sphere" string(1) "1" string(19) "2020-04-29 01:14:32" string(1) "3" nullstring(1) "6" string(8) "frontend" string(1) "3" string(6) "Sphere" string(1) "1" string(19) "2020-04-29 01:14:32" string(1) "3" null

Comment: @dalelandry i always get the array outputted, but the javascript only picks the 1st ID, each time i try to send the values using ajax post

Comment: @dalelandry i have also gotten the JSON state, but i don't what else is wrong....0: {task_id: "6", task_desc: "frontend", project_id: "3", company_id: "Sphere", user_id: "1", …}
1: {task_id: "7", task_desc: "Backend", project_id: "2", company_id: "Sphere", user_id: "1", …}
2: {task_id: "14", task_desc: "peanut lebel", project_id: "1", company_id: "Sphere", user_id: "1", …}
3: {task_id: "21", task_desc: "netflix page", project_id: "1", company_id: "Sphere", user_id: "1", …}
length: 4.          and perhaps, how do i echo it in the HTML value attribute?

Comment: Try wrapping your js in a for loop and use index to get each iteration see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649249/ajax-only-executing-first-iteration

Comment: @dalelandry which part of the code are you referring to, are you talking about the ajax post part that is sending to the PHP? Or you are referring to the part of getting the array values from the PHP?